# Unable to open Excel file using Pyexcel even after ininstalling pyexcel-xls and pyexcel-xlsx

Tags: python, excel, pyexcel

I try to open a simple excel file with pyexcel, however I get the following error:

```
SupportingPluginAvailableButNotInstalled: Please install one of these plugins for read data in 'xlsx': pyexcel-xls,pyexcel-xlsx
```

My code:

```
import pyexcel as pe
sheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name=k, name_columns_by_row=0,skip_empty_rows=True)
```

Things I have tried:

```
pip install pyexcel-xls;
pip install pyexcel-xlsx;
Use anaconda instead of IDLE;
reinstall Python 3.7
```

However, no luck

Full error:

```
runfile('H:/Data/Data/clean_data.py', wdir='H:/Data/Data')
Reloaded modules: d_help
.\added_c\profile1 (1).xlsx
[autoreload of pyexcel.internal failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 244, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "C:\Users\XX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 378, in superreload
    module = reload(module)
  File "C:\Users\XX\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 314, in reload
    return importlib.reload(module)
  File "C:\Users\XX\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 169, in reload
    _bootstrap._exec(spec, module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 630, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\XX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\internal\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    white_list=WHITE_LIST,
  File "C:\Users\XX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lml\loader.py", line 137, in scan_plugins_regex
    do_import(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\XX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lml\utils.py", line 42, in do_import
    return _do_import(plugin_module_name)
AttributeError: module 'pyexcel' has no attribute 'plugins'
]
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Could you please post a code sample for us?  It is hard for us to reproduce the error and offer suggestions without seeing what you are trying.

Comment: updated the code and shared the full error

Comment: This seems to work just fine with CPython.  Are you creating a virtual environment and/or are you using a non-CPython interpreter?

Comment: I am using just both IDLE and Spyder, but the problem persists